# Loop through Menu list items and add them up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamically created menu with parent items and child items. I would like to be able to loop through the child items to perform a count then append the child item with the count under the parent item

The data I grab from my SQL database is created into a menu list like so:

```
[{
  "ID": 9,
  "MenuText": "BMW",
  "ParentID": null,
  "Active": true,
  "List": [{
    "ID": 38,
    "MenuText": "M3",
    "ParentID": 9,
    "Active": true,
    "List": []
  }, {
    "ID": 39,
    "MenuText": "M3",
    "ParentID": 9,
    "Active": true,
    "List": []
  }]
}]
```

From here the child items reference to the parent item's ID: 9

Once the menu list has been generated I use the following JavaScript to build the menu into ul class="menu"

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({
    url: 'MenuHandler.ashx',
    method: 'get',
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      buildmenu($('.menu'), data);
      $('.menu').menu();

    }
  })

  function buildmenu(parent, items) {
    $.each(items, function() {
      var li = $('<li>' + this.MenuText + '</li>');
      if (!this.Active) {
        li.addclass('ui-state-disabled');
      }
      li.appendTo(parent);

      if (this.List && this.List.length > 0) {
        var ul = $('<ul></ul>');
        ul.appendTo(li);
        buildmenu(ul, this.List);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

This is how my menu is currently generated:
BMW > M3
      M3

This is how I would like my menu to generate:
BMW (2) > M3 (2)

I attempted to test a simple JavaScript for loop against the menu list items, but my alert message throws [object Object] during each loop.

```
setTimeout(function count() {
  var n = $('.menu li')
  for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
    alert(n)
  }
}, 3500);
```

Comment: It is normal that your alert message in the for loop throw [object Object] since you are alerting `n` ; a jQuery object ( `n= $('.menu li')` )!

Comment: another thing please, why do you need `BMW (2) > M3 (2)` instaed of `BMW (2) > M3` ? For me it is the latter that you need since there is no information about M3 count. Do you agree with me?

Comment: Well, I still ask about `BMW (2) > M3 (2)`, for me the first number `2` is for how much BMW exist and the second `2` if how much M3 exist, which is in contrast with you data structure. According to your data structure, the two M3 can contain different `List` arrays which oblige to display them separtely (ie `BMW (2) > M3 (0) , M3 (0)`). I hope I was clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `countOccurance` function to count and test if the menuText had aleready being added

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({
    url: 'MenuHandler.ashx',
    method: 'get',
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      buildmenu($('.menu'), data);
      $('.menu').menu();

    }
  })

  var lastliElement;// if more occurance append to the last element

  function buildmenu(parent, items) {
        var tabOccurance = [];
      $.each(items, function () {
            var nbOccurnace = countOccurance(this.MenuText,items);
          // search if occurance text alredy exist
          if(tabOccurance.indexOf(this.MenuText) == -1 ){ // this doesn't work on ecma6 and above
            var length = this.ParentID == null ? this.List.length : nbOccurnace;
            var li = $('<li>' + this.MenuText + '('+length+')' + '</li>');
            lastliElement = li;
            if (!this.Active) {
              li.addclass('ui-state-disabled');
            }

            li.appendTo(parent);

          }
          if(nbOccurnace>1) 
            tabOccurance.push(this.MenuText);

            if (this.List && this.List.length > 0) {

            var ul = $('<ul></ul>');
            ul.appendTo(lastliElement);
            buildmenu(ul, this.List);
          }
      });
  }
  // to conunt occurance of menuText
  function countOccurance(MenuText,list){
     var count = 0
     $.each(list, function () {
            if(this.MenuText === MenuText)
            count++;
     });
     return count;
  }
});
```

here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/89gceno1/2/).

Comment: Thank you! It worked out as intended. However, Do you know if there is a way to adjust the width for the dropdown on the child item? Now the (2) is placed under M3 instead of M3 (2).

Comment: Nevermind. Figured it out by changing CSS:
.dropdown-menu li {
    width: 200px !important;
    height: 30px !important;
}

Comment: Okey ,Glad it helps  you .

Answer (score 0):

To make things appear like `BMW (2) > M3` as per your sample data, one could use `data[i].List.length`:

```
function buildmenu(parent, items) {
    $.each(items, function () {
        var li = $('<li>' + this.MenuText +'(' + this.List.length + ')</li>');

    });
```

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/8cooqye8/1/